# From informal to formal sentences

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, vocabulary, formality

I need help because I don't know how to rewrite these sentencese in a formal way:

1) This is the area of research that he is working on.
2) Here are some new statistics that you can have confidence in.
3) This is a theory that there's little support for.
4) Is this the person who you entered into correspondence with?
5) The editor that she sent her article to has replied.
6) Unfortunately, the conference that you enrolled on has been cancelled.

Comment: When people are writing things "formally", they start each sentence ***with a capital letter***. Apart from that, it's just a matter of opinion whether any changes to your *phrasing* make the text more or less formal.

Comment: This appears to be an exercise to teach people that stranding prepositions is "informal", but pied-piping them (and using _whom_) is "formal". This is complete nonsense. Formality is not a matter of grammar. By all means, learn to recognize when others do it; but if you're learning English, don't try to write "formal" English by textbook standards. Nobody ever speaks that way, and only those trying to impress write that way.

Comment: Change 'that ... (preposition).' to '(preposition) which ...'. That's all.

Comment: I am studying to get a quite high English certificate, I know that nobody speaks that way but I may be asked to do it, that is why I needed to see how these sentences could be changed in a formal style. Thanks for the help anyways (:

Comment: What @JohnLawler said! Best advice I've seen yet on EL&U. "*Learn to recognize*... only. (And this question is primarily opinion-based.)

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb with dangling participles is,

- if writing do not use them
- if speaking, as you please

For purposes of written text:

1. This is the area of research in which he is working.
2. Here are some new statistics which will give you high confidence.
3. This is a theory for which there is little support.
4. Is this the person with whom you have entered/started correspondence?
5. The editor to whom she remitted her article has replied.
6. Unfortunately, the conference in which you have enrolled has been cancelled.